# Ajax pagination not working with wp-property plugin

Tags: ajax, wordpress, pagination

I'm using the wp-property plugin with Genesis Framework. The plugin has an ajax pagination in the properties page but is not working.

While testing I realized that it works fine with Twenty Fourteen theme, I posted it on the plugin forum suport and they told me that I'm getting this error:
'You don't have permission to access /cms/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php on this server.'

But I don't know how they are seeing it(because I can't see it with firebug) or why it's happening.

I tried the fixes of this post:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/dont-have-permission-admin-ajaxphp-add-new-category?replies=11

but is still not working.

The link to the website: [link](http://housesonthecoast.com/cms/properties)

Thanks!

Comment: you can use this simple pagination try this : https://github.com/manojdhiman/pagination

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't think it would work because I've already tried to use a custom template with genesis pagination and when I go to the secong page I get a 404 error, so I think the normal pagination(without ajax) is somehow restricted by the plugin.

You can see it here:[link](http://dqhweb.com/inmo/properties/)

I also posted this in the plugin forum but they told me that I need premium request($50) if I want to get an answer to that.. Thanks again anyway! I'll give it a try.

Comment: can you please show me the code???

Answer (score 0):

I figured out!

The plugin has a property overview template that can be customized by copying it into the theme directory and editing it, and it seems that it doesn't accept many changes because the problem was there. 
Deleting the customized template solved the issue.